# (Lucene/SOLR) Can I annotate the results of a query based on grouping by subqueries?

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I would like to group the results of any query in terms of "categories".

"Categories" are keyword queries, they cannot be pre-defined at index time, since they evolve and change over time.

More specifically:

I have a set of categories defined by queries *q1,q2,...qN*.

Given a user query (*q*), I need to return the top resulting docs (*d1,...d10*) as usual,

but I need to know if they belong or not to each of the groups *q1,...qN*.

As I understand it **I could use grouping with queries**, but this has two drawbacks:

1. I will change the results, since instead of *d1,...d10* I will get top docs for each query
2. I will loose the original ordering of the results

The only solution I can think of right now is to issue first *q* to get the results and ordering, then each of *q AND q1*, *q AND q2*, etc. to get the grouping, then parse all the results and group outside the query... expensive!

Any ideas how can I get what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the normal way to do the query, and then add pseudo-fields in fl param that matches the clipping against your categories using function queries.

http://solr.pl/en/2011/11/22/solr-4-0-new-fl-parameter-functionalities-first-look/
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries

Example:

fl=category1:sum(0.0, query($q1))

q1={!dismax}your query 1

fl=category2:sum(0.0, query($q2))

q2={!dismax}your query 2

Comment: works like a charm! Thanks this is exactly what I needed. _(te debo una cena!)_